# Order By not empty field first

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2 ActiveRecord to execute a query.
In my table I have two fields `reduced_price` (which can be empty) and `price`.  I would like the `Order By` to check `reduced_price` first, and if it is empty it use `price`.

My current code looks like this :

```
$this->db->select('*')
          ->from('products')
          ->order_by('reduced_price', 'desc')
          ->get()
          ->result();
```

How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: Simple just check weather your getting value in the first else use the second you could also Minmize  by using ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

Use case in query
       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER_BY CASE WHEN reduced_price IS NOT NULL  THEN reduced_price ELSE price END'
       $query= $this->db->query($sql);
       return $query->result_array();

Answer (score 0):

use case like this is sql query

ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN reduced_price IS NOT NULL THEN reduced_price END,
   CASE WHEN reduced_price IS NULL THEN price END